# Why blocking receives work and non-blocking don't

Tags: c, unix, ipc, message, message-queue

I was writing examples of blocking and non blocking receives.

I use msgrcv with IPC_NOWAIT  flag as a non - blocking receive

And msgrcv with 0 flag as blocking receive.

Then i sent some messages from another process.

If i try to use only blocking receives, they correctly receive the messages.

I tried also to put the non-blocking receives in a while cycle (they should work until a termination message arrives). But many non-blocking receives doesn't work. It seems that only the non-blocking receive that waits for the termination message works.

I post only the non-working code, obviously.

Receving program:

```
while(terminato == 0)
{msgrcv(id_interfaccia,&msg,dim,NOTIFICA_AVVIO_CONTROLLORE,IPC_NOWAIT);
if(errno==0)
{printf("Controllore avviato\n");
}
msgrcv(id_interfaccia,&msg,dim,NOTIFICA_AVVIO_MIXER,IPC_NOWAIT);
if(errno==0)
{printf("Mixer avviato\n");
}


msgrcv(id_interfaccia,&msg,dim,NOTIFICA_INTERRUZIONE_MIXER,IPC_NOWAIT);
if(errno==0)
{   printf("Il controllore ha inviato il messaggio di interruzione al mixer\n");
}
msgrcv(id_interfaccia,&msg,dim,NOTIFICA_INTERRUZIONE_TERMOSTATO,IPC_NOWAIT);
{printf("Il controllore ha inviato il messaggio di interruzione al termostato\n");
}
    msgrcv(id_interfaccia,&msg,dim,NOTIFICA_AVVIO_TERMOSTATO,IPC_NOWAIT);
{printf("Il controllore ha inviato il messaggio di avvio al termostato\n");
}

msgrcv(id_interfaccia,&msg,dim,NOTIFICA_TERMINAZIONE_MIXER,IPC_NOWAIT);
if(errno==0)
{   printf("Il controllore ha inviato il messaggio di terminazione al mixer\n");
}
    msgrcv(id_interfaccia,&msg,dim,NOTIFICA_TERMINAZIONE_TERMOSTATO,IPC_NOWAIT);
if(errno==0)
{   printf("Il controllore ha inviato il messaggio di terminazione al termostato\n");
}

msgrcv(id_interfaccia,&msg,dim,TEMP,IPC_NOWAIT);
if(errno==0)
{printf("INTERFACCIA Aggiornamento temperatura:%d\n",msg.contenuto);
}
msgrcv(id_interfaccia,&msg,dim,TERMINA,IPC_NOWAIT);
if(errno==0);
{printf("INTERFACCIA Messaggio di terminazione\n");     
terminato = 1;
}
}
```

Sending program

```
 invia(id_interfaccia,NOTIFICA_AVVIO_CONTROLLORE,&msg);
  invia(id_mixer,AVVIA,&msg);
 invia(id_interfaccia,NOTIFICA_AVVIO_MIXER,&msg);
 sleep(3);
 invia(id_mixer,INTERROMPI,&msg);
 invia(id_interfaccia,NOTIFICA_INTERRUZIONE_MIXER,&msg);
 invia(id_termostato,AVVIA,&msg);
 printf("Il controllore ha inviato il messaggio di avviamento al           termostato\n");

 while(check<50)
{
msgrcv(id_controllore,&msg,dim,TEMP,0);
check = msg.contenuto;
msg.tipo = TEMP;
msg.contenuto = check;
msgsnd(id_interfaccia,&msg,dim,0);
}
 invia(id_termostato,INTERROMPI,&msg);
 invia(id_interfaccia,NOTIFICA_INTERRUZIONE_TERMOSTATO,&msg);
 invia(id_mixer,TERMINA,&msg);
 invia(id_interfaccia,NOTIFICA_TERMINAZIONE_MIXER,&msg);
  invia(id_termostato,TERMINA,&msg);
```

Invia and ricevi functions:

```
void invia(int dest,int tipo,messaggio* pointer)
{pointer->tipo = tipo;
msgsnd(dest,pointer,dim,0);
}
void ricevi (int dest,int tipo,messaggio* pointer)
{msgrcv(dest,pointer,dim,tipo,0);
}
```

type struct Message has type (tipo) and content (contenuto) field.

Comment: Please show the code for your two cases, show the program output which you do not understand and say, what output you expected.

Comment: DOne. The problem is that only one/two printfs work

Comment: Please note that errno is only guaranteed to be set when msg* returns -1. You have to check the return value first.

Comment: A check like if(msgrcv()>0) will work?

Comment: Yes, I personally would use sth. like `st = msgrcv();  if (st < 0) { // Error handling }` for better readability